# Best practices for backing up company data?

Tags: backup, google, drive

Hopefully asked in the right website, as a company of 25 employees, we are using Google Drive for most of our data with automatic syncing. In case of a malware, these files would be deleted / encrypted due to the automatic syncing.

What would be the best practice for backing up these files offline? Is there a service which offers weekly Google Drive folder backups?

Answer (score 6):

3-2-1 rule all night long!

https://www.veeam.com/blog/the-3-2-1-0-rule-to-high-availability.html

https://knowledgebase.starwindsoftware.com/explanation/the-3-2-1-backup-rule/

I would revise your backup plan making sure your data is protected enough and you'd be able to restore it according to your company's RPO/RTO.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much data (that needs to be backed up) you have, you may want to consider the local backup repository on-site to improve your RTO.

If you feel confident going with Google drive, I suggest you look at something like this: https://www.backupify.com/google-drive-backup It will allow you to at least have a simple backup chain.